# I need to replace specific text in matrix

Tags: matrix

I have this matrix.

```
mat = RandomReal[{0, 2}, {10, 10}];

mat[[1, 3]] = mat[[6, 8]] = mat[[4, 4]] = mat[[10, 5]] = "Error";

mat[[2, 8]] = mat[[5, 3]] = mat[[4, 7]] = mat[[8, 7]] = "Blank";

mat//MatrixForm
```

and I need to replace `"Blank"` with arithmetic mean of all numbers in the given column.
Then I need to replace `"Error"` with the division of biggest and smallest number in the given row.

I can't do it alone and I really need it to pass my exams.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does what you are asking.

```
Do[
  With[{z = mat[[All, 3]]}, {mean = Mean[z /. "Blank" | "Error" -> Nothing]}, 
     mat[[All, col]] = z /. "Blank" -> mean],
  {col, Union[Position[mat, "Blank"][[All, 2]]]}]
Do[
  With[{z = mat[[row]]}, {new = Divide @@ Reverse[MinMax[z /. "Error" -> Nothing]]}, 
    mat[[row]] = z /. "Error" -> new],
  {row, Union[Position[mat, "Error"][[All, 1]]]}]
```

First the column numbers in which "Error" occurs are computed. Then for each column number, in the column the two strings are deleted and the mean is computed, "Error" is replaced with this mean and the column is adapted.

Then a similar construction is used for the rows.

Comment: There is a problem with too many arguments and mat[[All, col]] = z /. "Blank" -> mean] and mat[[row]] = z /. "Error" -> new] is red.

Comment: Yes, but you can neglect that. Already from version 10 (I think), `With` can be used with more than two arguments, in the way I did it, but so far the syntax colouring is not adapted.